# “state channel” v.s “micro-payment channel” : are they the same?

Tags: fees, scalability, payments, state-channels

We use "`micro-payment channels`" such as "[Bitcoin Lightning Network](https://dci.mit.edu/lightning-network/)" or "[Duplex Micro-Payment Channels](https://www.tik.ee.ethz.ch/file/716b955c130e6c703fac336ea17b1670/duplex-micropayment-channels.pdf)" for saving transaction fee, accelerating payments, supporting better micro-payment and scaling blockchain.

Is there any difference between "`state channel`" v.s "`micro-payment channe`l"? and if so, what are **differences**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A payment channel is essentially a subset of a state channel. (The state being tracked is how much currency is owed to each participant.)